# Fiddler is not showing HTTPS traffic

Tags: https, fiddler

I enabled "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" and "Ignore server certificate errors" in Fiddler but the traffic of one website is not being showed.

This is the error that Fiddler is returning:

> [Fiddler] The connection to '...' failed.  System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS
>   connection with server.fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to
>   ... failed. System.IO.IOException Received an unexpected EOF
>   or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

I remember that I could ignore this error in Fiddler script, but I really don't remember.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 5):

What is the site's URL?

It is probably caused by either of these two issues: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/08/aes-is-not-a-valid-cipher-for-sslv3.aspx or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2012/03/29/https-request-hangs-.net-application-connection-on-tls-server-name-indicator-warning.aspx

The old workaround is to configure Fiddler to only use SSL3 when talking to the host in question. The newer workaround is to either use Fiddler4 with the latest .NET4.5.2 framework, or if you're using Fiddler 2.5.1, see the "SNI Hack" section of http://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-s-new-in-fiddler-4-5-1

In your OnBeforeRequest event handler, add the following code to fix the issue for certain sites:

```
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") && oSession.HostnameIs("BuggySite.com")) 
{ 
  oSession["https-DropSNIAlerts"] = "yup"; 
  FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString("Legacy compat applied for request to BuggySite.com"); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you.changing the enabled protocols to only ssl3 solved the issue for me

Comment: Generally speaking, you want to avoid doing that as it will break for other sites. See the updated answer.

Comment: 17:48:52:7150 Legacy compat applied for request to BuggySite.com  
17:48:52:8420 fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to public.msrtcors.com (for #808) failed. System.IO.IOException Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.          I get this error even after putting the hack in the custom rules. The Log show that the hack gets executed. Yet it does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Yash: What's the actual URL? Debugging telepathically doesn't work.

Comment: This is what I added in the custom rules: if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") && oSession.HostnameIs("public.msrtcors.com")) 
  { 
    oSession["https-DropSNIAlerts"] = "yup"; 
    FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString("Legacy compat applied for request to BuggySite.com"); 
  }

Comment: Upgraded .NET to 4.5.2. The problem persists.

Comment: StackOverflow comments aren't the proper way to ask new questions. This server's problem isn't related to SNI; the server requires TLS/1.2. You need to enable TLS/1.2 in Fiddler to connect to this server; see http://www.telerik.com/blogs/fiddler-and-modern-tls-versions.  Unrelated but interesting: it's vulnerable to a padding attack: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=public.msrtcors.com.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late for the poster unfortunately but I just needed to add tls1.2:

1. Tools
2. Options
3. HTTPS
4. Protocols
5. Add tls1.2 to the end of the list and click ok

Comment: You can also _temporarily_ enable Capture HTTPS to set this and then disable it once again if you're not interested in Capturing HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the following exception:

> System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection
> with server.fiddler.network.https. HTTPS handshake to
> api.etadirect.com (for #9) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to
> read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host. An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host

I was able to fix it by enabling the TLS1.2 protocol which is not enabled by default for outgoing connections
Tools -> Options -> HTTPS -> click on protocols list
[image]

Comment: Hi All, after adding the tls1.2 to the protocols there is no error on handshake but still no traffic is appearing what is creating this situation?