# No outbound traffic when sending XML to client's endpoint on UAT web server (Fiddler example)

Tags: c#, php, xml, web-services, wcf

I have a problem when I try to send XML to an external client's endpoint (Example: https://dev.hostname.com:4969/dir/dir.page.php).

I get this error back when I try it from a .NET WCF web service and from Fiddler from our UAT web server:

> [Fiddler] The connection to 'dev.hostname.com' failed.  System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS
>   connection with server.fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to
>   dev.kmcis.com failed. System.IO.IOException Received an unexpected EOF
>   or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

It works fine if I try the same from my development box (I get back an expected XML stream that confirms that it was successful).

This is what I am trying in Fiddler:

1. Go to the "Composer" tab
2. Select "POST"
3. Plug in the endpoint URL (https://dev.hostname.com:4969/dir/dir.page.php), and
4. Plug this XML into the "Request Body" text box:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Fulfillment>
    <FileNumber>###-######</FileNumber>
    <OrderID>#</OrderID>
    <LegalDescription>Blah blah blah</LegalDescription>
</Fulfillment>
```

5. Click the "Execute" button.

I have already tried the suggestions from [Fiddler is not showing HTTPS traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944280/fiddler-is-not-showing-https-traffic), but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas as to what could be preventing our UAT web server from sending any outbound traffic to this external client's endpoint, yet my development box can send to and receive XML successfully from it?

Comment: "Any ideas" should qualify for any duplicate. Please make more specific how your question is different from the many (then to be referenced and explained) Q&A material that is about the same exception message and on site already.

Comment: We figured out a solution. The development box had the .NET 4.5 as the latest .NET framework installed whereas all our servers had .NET 4.0 as the latest .NET framework installed. We installed .NET 4.5 on our UAT web server and it worked instantly. I'm not exactly sure why because our client's endpoint is php.